# Why does getScaleY() always returns 1.0? [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an `ImageView` that contains an image. This image is getting scaled to fit within the screen because it's too large.

I'm trying to find out how much the image has scaled using `getScaleY()` and `getScaleX()`. This *should* return `1.0` if the image has not been scaled and return some value less than `1.0` if the image is scaled down to fit the view.

Instead, `getScaleX()` and `getScaleY()` alsways return `1.0` for me whether the image is scaled down or not.

You can see my XML here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/docImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dossier_cover"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or am I better off finding out the scale in a different way?

Comment: Also I've tried setting the adjustViewBounds to false but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I called `getScaleX()` before it was drawn.
Mystery solved.