# How can i get the current scale of a webView(android)

Tags: android, webview, scale

getScale ()  was deprecated in API level 17. so , how can i get the current scale of a webview. 
i tried to override the method onScaleChanged, but it won`t be called unless i change the scale...

Comment: What did you use instead of getScale() ?

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is a bit old, but this may help someone (like me), especially if someone wants to override WebView and add onTouch listener, to detect WebView's content end.

You can use:

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

instead of

```
webView.getScale()
```

which is deprecated.

It is the same value, that represents screen density, compared to `mdpi` value.
So, it will be as follows:

- ldpi: 0.75
- mdpi: 1.0
- hdpi: 1.5
- xhdpi: 2.0
- xxhdpi: 3.0
- xxxhdpi: 4.0

Comment: No, I get completely different values for webview.scale, webview.scaleY and resources.displayMetrics.density.

Answer (score 2):

`WebView.getScaleX()` and `WebView.getScaleY()` might help, is this what you want?

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your questions, so I'll just give an answer. Hope this helps (:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. getScale returns 2. but getScaleX and getScaleY returns 1. I don`t know what that means..

Comment: Does both getScaleX() and getScaleY() return 1? It means the current view is 1.0x than the origin view, which means no scaling is implied. And I don't know why getScale() returns 2. Sorry for that.

Comment: that`s all right. I think getScaleX/Y return the view scale not the webpage scale..

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279613/why-does-getscaley-always-returns-1-0-android