# What is the default scale value of the WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview

The Android [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getScale()) says that `getScale()` method was deprecated.
I have implemented `onScaleChanged(WebView, float, float)` to get the new scale, but this method is triggered only when the scale is changed.

So, what is the default scale value for the webview?
From the `getScale()` method, it is `2.0f`, but is this value always 2.0f on all devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Developers [WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), the scaling depends on the pixel density on the screen of the device:

> By default, WebView scales a web page so that it is drawn at a size that matches the default appearance on a medium density screen. So, **it applies 1.5x scaling on a high density screen (because its pixels are smaller) and 0.75x scaling on a low density screen (because its pixels are bigger).** Starting with API level ECLAIR, WebView supports DOM, CSS, and meta tag features to help you (as a web developer) target screens with different screen densities.

Further information is found on the page [Supporting Different Screens in Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportScale), where there is information (and sample code) to query the device density with JavaScript:

> ```
> if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1.5) {
>   alert("This is a high-density screen");
> } else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 0.75) {
>   alert("This is a low-density screen");
> }
> ```

Comment: So, is there anyway to get the initial value from the code?

Comment: Am not entirely sure about that; however, there are ways to specify the scaling, which incidently only is 0.75, 1.0 and 1.5 for low, medium and high density screen devices.

Comment: @user2447581 I found some information (and code) that allows the specific scale factor used to be found.

Comment: Very late to the party... But look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25787425/9625282 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density should do the trick.